# Run SQL Query From Button Press Event

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using PHP and am wanting to run a sql query on a button press event.  I have this synatx, but the problem I have is nothing happens when the button is pressed!  I opened the developer console and I see no action from where the button is pressed.

What did I improperly code here and how shoudl I change it so that it executes as I expect?

```
    <html>
<tbody> 
Start Date:<input type="date" name="startdate">
End Date:<input type="date" name="enddate">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Query DB">
</tbody>
</html>
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $startdate = $_GET['startdate'];
    $enddate = $_GET['enddate'];
    $option = array();
    $option['driver'] = 'mssql'; 
    $option['host'] = 'IP Address'; 
    $option['user'] = 'user'; 
    $option['password'] = 'pwd'; 
    $option['database'] = 'DB'; 
    $option['prefix'] = '';
    $db = JDatabase::getInstance( $option );
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query = "Select Top 1 firstname from userinformation where hiredate >= '$startdate' and termdate < '$enddate'"; 
    $db->setQuery($query); 
    $query = $db->loadObjectList();
}
?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a jQuery AJAX post method like this on the client-side:

```
$("#form_id").submit(function( event ) {
  $.post( "", {startdate: $("#form_id :input[name='startdate']"), enddate: $("#form_id :input[name='enddate']");} , function( data ) {
    // handle the returning data if you need
  });
});
```

`$("#form_id").submit(function( event )` listens for the form submission event of the from with `id="from_id"`.

`$("#form_id :input[name='startdate']")` gets the input value.

Then lastly [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) method sends a JSON object like `{startdate: "01.01.2016", enddate: "12.31.2016"}` to the server.

I wrote `""` as the target of POST method, it could be like `"/myScript.php"` in your case.

On server-side [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) variable of PHP parses the request automatically.

Also you need to change these two lines on the server-side:

```
$startdate = $_POST['startdate'];
$enddate = $_POST['enddate'];
```

because you are using `POST` method to send your data, not `GET` method.

*Note: Question tagged with jquery so I assumed that request should be handled by jQuery.*

Answer (score 1):

A submit button needs to be inside  tags. Specifically, you will need to have `<form method="POST">` at a minimum as the default is GET which would put the data in $_GET instead of $_POST. Actually, I see you have an inconsistency here - some $_GET and some $_POST - that definitely won't work right - needs to be all one or the other.

To "keep" the values on reload of the form, change the input lines to:

```
Start Date:<input type="date" name="startdate" value=<?=$_POST['startdate']?>">
End Date:<input type="date" name="enddate" value="<?=$_POST['enddate']?>">
```

Comment: To my understanding - I have to use $_Post with the button press, so I should change my variable captures to $_Post also?  I will add in a <form method="POST"> at the top as well :)

Comment: Beautiful!  That did it!!  Is there anyway that I can keep the values selected for start and end even after the button is pressed?

Comment: This answer does not include **jquery**. OP tagged his/her question with jquery and ajax tag. @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh my answer is using jQuery AJAX approach to handle the request dynamically. (so probably this is what you are looking for)